# Pop-up window not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a .net page which needs to open a new pop-up window when certain conditions are not met in the code behind file. I have the following code:

```
private bool isValidPart(string partNo)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(partNo))
    {
        DataBase.DBManager dm = new DBManager();

        if (!Convert.ToBoolean(dm.ExecScalar("usp_getPart", partNo)))
        {
            string url = "test.aspx";
            string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I put a break point and verified it. It hits the line but the pop-up window does not open up. It just simply moves to next line and returns false.

May I please know the reason behind it?

---

@yog2411 This is the code which checks that isvalidpart()

```
                                             private bool SetRowData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentData"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentData = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentData.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentData.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox TextCustomerName = (TextBox)gvInventory.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtCustomerName");
                    TextBox TextPONumber = (TextBox)gvInventory.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtPONumber");
                    TextBox TextPartNumber = (TextBox)gvInventory.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtPartNumber");
                    TextBox TextQuantity = (TextBox)gvInventory.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtQuantity");
                    //TextBox TextReqShipDate = (TextBox)gvInventory.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("txtReqShipDate");
                    if (!isValidPart(TextPartNumber.Text))
                        return false;
                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentData.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;
                    dtCurrentData.Rows[i - 1]["CustName"] = TextCustomerName.Text; 
                    dtCurrentData.Rows[i - 1]["PONum"] = TextPONumber.Text;
                    dtCurrentData.Rows[i - 1]["PartNum"] = TextPartNumber.Text;
                    dtCurrentData.Rows[i - 1]["Qty"] = TextQuantity.Text;
                   // dtCurrentData.Rows[i - 1]["ReqShipDate"] = TextReqShipDate.Text;                     
                    rowIndex++;                      
                }
                ViewState["CurrentData"] = dtCurrentData;
                gvInventory.DataSource = dtCurrentData;
                gvInventory.DataBind();}
        }
        SetPreviousData();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: any errors in console??

Comment: The pop-up window will not open until the current `Request` has finished executing.  The pop-up can't open whilst you are sat on a breakpoint.  What happens if you let this code run?

Comment: May be U face some javascript error>or you use updatepanel on the page

Comment: tell me if using Response.Write(s) instead ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript it works

Comment: @just_name I don't have much of javascript in my code. I just have a panel which has gridview inside it. Is that going to be a problem?

Comment: @MartinParkin It didn't run even if i run the full code without breakpoints. It just moves to the next page.

Comment: @use a firebug to detect if u have some script error blocked your popup window

Comment: @yog2411 No errors. Everything works fine. I dunno it just neglects that line and moves to next.

Comment: @HariAnandan what happens if you remove return false ?

Comment: and what about using Response.Write(s)???

Comment: I tried the exact same code and its working on my side. which browser you are using ? make sure it doesn't block the pop up windows!!!!

Comment: @lem2802 It doesn't work buddy. I even tried with www.google.com, it doesn't open up

Comment: @yog2411 I removed false but it doesn't have any effect. I tried using chrome and firefox. It doesn't work in both the browser's. Do you think if there is any other mistakes I am doing?

Comment: it seems to be working fine on my end. I have simple blank page without script manager or update panel. Would be more helpful if you share more code and aspx code as well.

Comment: @yog2411 Ok. Let me explain. I have a .aspx code which gets user input. The main thing there is "Part number" field. Once when the user clicks the "Recieve parts" button, the code behind will check in the database whether the part is already available or not. If it is not available, it show pop up the "Createpart.asp" page and ask the user to create the part. In the end, once when the user clicks the "create" button in that page, it shld close that pop-up window and it should proceed to another .aspx page. I hope I have made the idea clear. I am wondering if there could be thread problem?

Comment: @yog2411 This is the code which checks that isvalidpart(). I have added it in the answers

Answer (score 0):

try writing a JS function

```
function showMyPopUp(myUrl) {
    //I have this settings and it works like a popUp, 
    //I just going to write the properties you have, but you can change them for these ones
    //var CustomFeatures = 'titlebar=no, status=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,location=no,width=300,height=100,top=100,left=100';
    var CustomFeatures = 'resizable=yes,width=300,height=100,top=100,left=100';
    window.open(myUrl, '_blank', CustomFeatures, true);
}
```

and in your C# this

```
string url = "test.aspx";
string myCallfunction = "showMyPopUp('" + url + "');"
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Funct", myCallfunction , true);
```

hope it helps